# Selecting with multiple conditions from one dataset

Tags: sql

I have a Table that has 5 columns

[image: TableA]

First you can see that im german. But second you see that much of the data only differs in the category and value.

I now want to find all the Datasets that have category 1 and value 1
It should give me this table

[image: tableafiltered]

I now whant to find in the initial TableA all the entrys that match Name, Date and City BUT only if all 3 of them for every dataset match AND the category is now 2 instead of 1 AND the Value is 0.

So for the Table A it should come out as:

[image: FinishedTable]

I hope i didnt do any mistakes. In the example and it is clear what i try.

I know for the WHERE Statement there is an IN clause that basically checks if the value is inside a list of values. But i dont know how to use this to check for 3 Values. Because when i just do 3 Lists checks it would also give me every entry that is a combination of my 3 lists regardles of which row the actual value comes from.

So instead of checking if value Name[0] And City[0] And Date[0] can be found i need to avoid that a value is found that is like Name[0] City[4] and Date[12] (Number in brackets stands for the row number).

The code i would have thought of:

```
Select*
FROM tablea

WHERE

(SELECT name, date, city
FROM tablea
WHERE tablea.Category=1 AND tablea.Value=0) as tableafiltered

WHERE tablea in tableafiltered
```

Thats what i thought would maybe work. But im pretty sure it wouldnt work. Because im trying to match 3 Columns. And the in in the where statement is only valid for one column right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first dataset that you describe can be a subquery and you can join it to the table:

```
select t.* 
from tablea t inner join (
  select distinct name, date, city 
  from tablea
  where category = 1 and value = 1 
) d on d.name = t.name and d.date = t.date and d.city = t.city
where t.category = 2 and t.value = 0
```

Another way of doing it is with EXISTS:

```
select t.* 
from tablea t 
where t.category = 2 and t.value = 0
and exists (
  select 1 
  from tablea 
  where name = t.name and date = t.date and city = t.city and category = 1 and value = 1 
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=14601697dafb02df6325169437d6fdc6).
Results:

```
> name   | date       | city    | category | value
> :----- | :--------- | :------ | -------: | ----:
> Albert | 01.01.2000 | Berlin  |        2 |     0
> Albert | 01.01.2000 | Hamburg |        2 |     0
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create two selects, one for category=1, value=1, and one for the 2,0 combination. Then you can inner join  the two tables in one row, then ensure the other two columns matches by where table1.column1=table2.column1 and table2.column2=table1.column2. You can choose the columns any way you like, that's why I give this generic form.